# Memory leak on Wildfly 10.1.0.FINAL (java.lang.ref.Finalizer / ActiveMQConnection)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, finalizer, finalize, activemq-artemis

We have a java web application that sends (JobsController.java) and receives messages (JMSMessageListener.java) via JMS.  After running the application under constant load for 24 hours and taking heap dumps, I observe a constant increase in memory usage that the application does not let go when in idle state. I know that this is going to cause a java heap out of memory issue.

JobsController is an ejb stateless bean and its resources are destroyed correctly after each call.
JMSMessageListener gets handled by ejb global bean pool and its instance is reused.

The suspects i can see from the java heap dump are

1. EJB bean injection is causing a memory leak
   https://blog.akquinet.de/2017/01/04/dont-get-trapped-into-a-memory-leak-using-cdi-instance-injection/
2. ActiveMQConnection.finalize(). If it is the culprit than it must
   happen to all those wildfly activemq deployments. Any hint is
   appreciated.

**ActiveMQConnection.java**

```
@Override  
protected final void finalize() throws Throwable {  
   if (!closed) {  
       if (this.factoryReference.isFinalizeChecks()) {  
           ActiveMQJMSClientLogger.LOGGER.connectionLeftOpen(creationStack);  
       }  
       close();  
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**JobsController**

@Stateless
public class JobsController {

```
@Inject  
private JMSContext jmsContext;  
private Connection connection;  
private Session session;  
private MessageProducer jmsProducer;  

@Resource(lookup = "java:/ConnectionFactory")  
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;  

@Resource(lookup = JAVA_JMS_JOB_QUEUE)  
private Queue jobQueue;  

@Resource(lookup = JAVA_JMS_QUEUE)  
private Queue progressQueue;  

@PreDestroy  
void release() {  
    try {  
        if (jmsProducer != null) {  
            jmsProducer.close();  
        }  
        if (session != null) {  
            session.close();  
        }  
        if (jmsContext != null) {  
            jmsContext.close();  
        }  
        if (connection !=null) {  
            connection.close();  
        }  
    } catch (JMSException e) {  
        LOG.warn("failed to close JMS resources: {}", e.getMessage());  
    }  
}  

public synchronized MessageProducer getJmsProducer() {  
    if (jmsProducer == null) {  
        try {  
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();  
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  
            jmsProducer = session.createProducer(jobQueue);  


            connection.start();  
        } catch (JMSException e) {  
            LOG.error("failed to setup JMS message producer: {}", e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  
    return jmsProducer;  
}
public void addMessageToProgressQueue(ProgressMessage progressMessage) {
    ObjectMessage objectMessage = jmsContext.createObjectMessage(progressMessage);
    try {
        getJmsProducer().send(progressQueue, objectMessage);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        LOG.error("failed to send progress message {}: {}", objectMessage, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

**JMSMessageListener.java**

```
@MessageDriven(name = "JMSMessageListener", mappedName = JAVA_JMS_QUEUE, activationConfig = {  
        @ActivationConfigProperty(  
                propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",  
                propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),  
        @ActivationConfigProperty(  
                propertyName = "destinationType",  
                propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),  
        @ActivationConfigProperty(  
                propertyName = "destination",  
                propertyValue = JAVA_JMS_QUEUE)  


})  
public class JMSMessageListener implements MessageListener {  

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSMessageListener.class);  

    @EJB  
    private JobsController jobsController;  

    private final ObjectMapper progressMessageMapper;  

    public JMSMessageListener() {  
        progressMessageMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
        progressMessageMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onMessage(Message message) {  
        ProgressMessage progressMessage = null;  
        try {  
            if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {  
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) message;  
                int TEXT_LENGTH = new Long(bytesMessage.getBodyLength()).intValue();  
                byte[] textBytes = new byte[TEXT_LENGTH];  
                bytesMessage.readBytes(textBytes, TEXT_LENGTH);  


                String progressText = new String(textBytes, "UTF-8");  

                progressText = progressText.replaceAll("'totalSteps': None", "'totalSteps': 0");  
                progressMessage = progressMessageMapper.readValue(progressText, ProgressMessage.class);  
            } else if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {  
                progressMessage = message.getBody(ProgressMessage.class);  
            }  
            if (progressMessage != null) {  

                jobsController.sendProgressMessage(progressMessage);  
            } else {  
                LOG.error("An empty progress message was received");  
            }  
        } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {  
            LOG.error("failed to process progress message: {}", e.getMessage(), e);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- You're injecting a JMSContext but never using it (at least in the code that you pasted).  This seems like an error.
- If you aren't going to use the injected JMSContext but rather use the injected ConnectionFactory then you should be injecting "java:/JmsXA" rather than "java:/ConnectionFactory" since it is a &tl;pooled-connection-factory>. Creating a connection for every message sent with "java:/ConnectionFactory" is an anti-pattern since it is not pooled. Also, I assume you'd want to use an XA transaction so that message consumption and sending in your MDB is atomic and that won't work with "java:/ConnectionFactory".

Comment: Hi @Justin, Thank you for your suggestions.  I am trying out your suggestion to use "java:/JmsXA" instead of "java:/ConnectionFactory" and have some stress test running, to see if it still leaks. We do use JMSContext (added it above to the class JobsController).